# how to make emacs + egg (git) work with remote files (accessed via ssh)

Tags: git, emacs, ssh, tramp, sshfs

I have emacs + egg working correctly when accessing repos/dirs/files that are in my local system.

Also, opening and editing files via ssh works fine, e.g.

```
ctrl-f /ssh:jds@dev.acme.com:/home/jds/src/test.py
```

but then when executing egg-status, I get...

```
Opening input file: no such file or directory, /HEAD
```

Note that if I open a shell and ssh into the remote system, all git commands work correctly.

Thanks for any help to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13890975/462302) that you should use the more advanced and awesome [magit package](http://philjackson.github.com/magit/).

The longer story about why egg doesn't work the way you want is this: The way egg is written it *cannot* operate on remote files with TRAMP because egg.el uses the `call-process` function, whereas [magit](http://philjackson.github.com/magit/) uses `start-file-process` which is supported as described in the [Remote Processes section of the TRAMP manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Remote-processes.html):

```
5.4 Integration with other Emacs packages.

tramp supports running processes on a remote host. This allows to
exploit Emacs packages without modification for remote file names.
[...]
process-file and start-file-process work on the remote host when the
variable default-directory is remote:

     (let ((default-directory "/ssh:remote.host:"))
       (start-file-process "grep" (get-buffer-create "*grep*")
                           "/bin/sh" "-c" "grep -e tramp *"))
```

Comment: thanks for explaining why egg cannot work (as currently implemented); this explains the ssh (TRAMP) problem (and a good enough reason to look at alternatives to egg); still wondering about the sshfs problem, where emacs is not using ssh/TRAMP and seems to be opening the mounted files as any other regular local file.

Comment: I'm not sure why sshfs isn't working. Can you update your question with exact instructions to reproduce the problem? Also, what version of emacs and egg are you using? `M-x emacs-version` and `M-: egg-version`

Comment: was collecting some info and noticed that even regular git commands (i.e. executed from the shell) don't work when executed from the mounted dir (i.e. it's NOT emacs). git commands work ok if I ssh to the remove system. I'll update the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The [magit package](http://philjackson.github.com/magit/) works fine with remote files (just re-checked :-). And I think, that it most advanced between all Emacs/Git packages.

Comment: For me magit doesn't work over ssh using tramp. It always fails on commit. I can stage and other operations, but commit always fails.